# Tor can't connect to my internet

Tags: connection

It says "Tor failed to establish a Tor network connection.  Connecting to a relay directory failed (insufficient resources 77.247.181.164:443) "

is there a solution to this?  thanks!

Comment: Can you give us more information? Can we get the full log output instead of just a snippet of one line? What operating system? What version of Tor?

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I hadn't burrowed deep enough into the Tor browser folders but when i did i found the tor.exe file which i then gave access through my firewall and, voila, Tor Browser works fine. I hope the OP and others find this helpful.

Answer (score -2):

ISP maybe blocking. Try with a Free VPN running.

Comment: This answer is guess work, *and* a VPN is *not* the recommended remedy to ISPs blocking Tor access. Using pluggable transports and bridges would be the appropriate solution.